# how to replace string using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following string: `$str = '"FirstName":"first name","LastName":"Last name","AskCatalog":false,"Nuteres":61","ZipCode":"1234"'`

and I need to replace value of ,for example, FirstName:"`first name`" with a variable like this

```
"FirstName":"$strFristname"
```

Can anyone show me how can I do that in PowerShell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$str -replace '("FirstName":)".*?"', "`$1`"$strFirstname`""
```

The pattern `("FirstName":)".*?"` matches the string `"FirstName":` followed by a double quote and the shortest match of any character (`.*?`) up to the next double quote. The parentheses create a group that can be referenced by `$1` in the replacement string. Due to the double quotes around the replacement string that reference must be escaped (`` `$1 ``). The same goes for the nested double quotes (`` `" ``).

If you want the variable instead of its value to show up in the result, you need to escape the `$` of the variable as well:

```
$str -replace '("FirstName":)".*?"', "`$1`"`$strFirstname`""
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $str = '"FirstName":"first name","LastName":"Last name"'
PS C:\> $strFirstname = 'Joe'
PS C:\> $str -replace '("FirstName":)".*?"', "`$1`"$strFirstname`""
"FirstName":"Joe","LastName":"Last name"
PS C:\> $str -replace '("FirstName":)".*?"', "`$1`"`$strFirstname`""
"FirstName":"$strFirstname","LastName":"Last name"
```

Comment: Don't you forgot a ` before the $ in the replacing part ?

Comment: @JPBlanc My understanding was that he wanted the value of the variable, not the variable itself. If he wants the variable then you're right. Expanded my answer to cover that.

Comment: @JPBlanc: No I want to insert a variable in place of the name. It is  strange I know but that's how they require it.